# Azure Mobile Services app crashes with message- The app is not configured correctly to use Live Connect services

Tags: azure, windows-8, azure-mobile-services

***I am developing an store app .The ClientID and Client Secret on manage.dev.live.com have been copied to "identity" tab of my mobile services on Azure portal  and the redirect domain on both the manage.dev and Azure portal do match.
Also i have associated my store application with the app in manage.dev.live.com from inside VS .
But still i am receiving an error in my app.***FYI i am using different live accounts for dev.live.com and for Azure Portal , i dont know if that has any effect. On putting breakpoint , the error occurs at following line -

```
 LiveLoginResult result = await liveidclient.LoginAsync(new[] { "wl.basic" });
```

BTW , i do get the login prompt to enter username and passwd .After clicking OK ,the app crashes with message -The app is not configured correctly to use Live Connect services. To configure your app, please follow the instructions on

Hi , this is my exception details-

Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException was unhandled
      HResult=-2146233088
      Message=The app is not configured correctly to use Live Connect services. To configure your app, please follow the instructions on http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=220871.
      Source=Microsoft.Live
      ErrorCode=invalid_request
      StackTrace:
           at Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthClient.d_*4.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
           at DeltaVMobile.MainPage.<Authenticate>d__4.MoveNext() in MainPage.xaml.cs:line 99
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at DeltaVMobile.MainPage.<OnNavigatedTo>d__0.MoveNext() in MainPage.xaml.cs:line 75
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)
           at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
           at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
      InnerException: 
           HResult=-2138701823
           Message=Authentication target is invalid or not configured correctly. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80860001)
           Source=mscorlib
           StackTrace:
                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
                at Microsoft.Live.TailoredAuthClient.d*_12.MoveNext()
             --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
                at Microsoft.Live.TailoredAuthClient.d__0.MoveNext()
           InnerException:

The following is the code i am using

```
LiveAuthClient liveidclient = new LiveAuthClient("https://deltavauth.azure-mobile.net/");

            while (session == null)
            {
                if (liveidclient.CanLogout)
                {
                    liveidclient.Logout();
                }

                LiveLoginResult result = await liveidclient.LoginAsync(new[] { "wl.basic" });
                if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    session = result.Session;
                    LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
                    LiveOperationResult mresult = await client.GetAsync("me");
                    MobileServiceUser loginresult = await App.MobileService.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(result.Session.AuthenticationToken);
                    string title = string.Format("Welcome {0} !", mresult.Result["first_name"]);
                    var message = string.Format("You are now logged in -{0}", loginresult.UserId);
                    var dialog = new MessageDialog(title);
                    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
                    await dialog.ShowAsync();

                }
                else
                {
                    session = null;
                    var dialog = new MessageDialog("You must login to use DeltaV", "Login Required");
                    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
                    await dialog.ShowAsync();
                }
```

FYI , this is the URL for the tutorial -http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-windows-8-dotnet/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**https://manage.dev.live.com/ is deprecated**

You need to associate your app to your Windows Store account then and then you can use Live services & push notifications.

1. Right click on project name.
2. Click on "Store" menu.
3. Click "Associate App with the Store".
4. It will prompt you for login. Do login with your store account.
5. Click on the reserved name of your app (I think you must have reserved your app name otherwise go to [Windows Store Dashboard](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=233762) and first reserve it.)
6. Follow the other process which prompts.
7. You project will get `Store Key` & new `Package Identity`. So it will allow you to leverage Live services & push notifications.

Comment: I did associate my App with App Store from the Store menu option by right clicking on the project. I as able to find my Reserved Name from the wizard and was able to associate it with my project. I also looged into Manage.dev and Copied the Client secret key and Client ID into the Identity tab of my mobile service and the Redirect Domain on the Manage.dev and Azure do match. Also i am usign the mobile service given to my by azure in my app. Point is my App brings in the login windows ,and gives me further prompt saying it will access the account and friends and other settings etc

Comment: After Clicking OK on this prompt it crashed with the log i had pasted earlier. Can you please help me in this regard?

Comment: Why are you still using data from `Manage.dev` ?

Comment: so what should i put in the Client Key and Client Fields in Azure Mobile service? Should i reference them anywhere in app?

Comment: You will get client key & secret from Windows Store, see [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/svVCv.png)

Comment: ,I am getting the client secret from Windows store dashboard. I have this image attached -http://imgur.com/qBofclu. As for the client key  i cannot find it there.

Comment: Client key can be acquired from Windows Azure Dashboard.

Comment: we dont get client key (id) from Azure Dashboard. Client secret i can get from store dashboard. Refer image here -http://imgur.com/bxUiaos